# Transforming Functions

Tags: graphing-functions

I am reviewing some lessons in my textbook for school.

In this example:

y = f(x)

Graph: h(x) = f(1/2x)

For h(x), the book says that 1/2x is dividing each x coordinate by 1/2, but when I look at this, I think that you would multiply each x coordinate by 1/2. What am I not getting?

From the book:
"Graph h(x) = f(1/2(x)). Horizontally stretch the graph of y = f(x). Divide each x-coordinate by 1/2, which is the same as multiplying by 2."

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $(1/2)x$ where you wrote $1/2x$. You should also quote the book's words exactly.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have been getting so frustrated with this that my typing is furious.
Here it is: "Graph h(x) = f(1/2(x)). Horizontally stretch the graph of y = f(x). Divide each x-coordinate by 1/2, which is the same as multiplying by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a graph plotting $f(x)$ for all $x$. 
However, at any $x$, h(x) will plot $f(\frac{x}{2})$.

Now consider what this means. If we take the value of $h(x)$ at $x=a$, we will only get the same value on $f(x)$ at $x=2a$. 
This means the graph of $h(x)$ stretches $f(x)$ by a factor of 2, which you can see in the graph.

[image: This]